# How to recursively check for java array palindrome?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm stuck on a java assignment wherein I'm asked to design a recursive palindrome method that checks an integer array, returns true if it is a palindrome, false if it is not. So far I know the base case is that if the array is empty, or if it has only one element, it returns true. But I'm not sure how to start with the rest. Please help! Thank you!
This is what I have so far:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    if(array.length == 0 || array.length == 1)
        return true;

    if(start >= end)
        return true;

    if(array[start] != array[end])
        return false;

    return palindrome(array, start + 1, end -1);
}
```

Comment: you start by (step 1) analysing the problem (step 2) implementing your analysis by writing code

Comment: I think you should be able to figure this one out.  The essence of recursion is that you're solving a problem by solving the same problem on a smaller input (in this case, a smaller array).  Try writing some 3- and 4-element palindromic arrays on paper, and see if you can figure out how to reduce it to a smaller problem.

Comment: @STaefi Sorry, that's not quite correct; this *is* a Q&A site.  There are plenty of questions and answers.  The bottom of this page says "Know someone who can **answer**?  Share a link to this **question**...".  We just don't like people asking us to tell them how to write code before they've made any effort themselves.

Comment: @ajb: Dear ajb, you know what I mean, that we don't answer people's how to write their homeworks and programming projects. Actually we help them with their problems in their code. Isn't it better to ask such questions as **How to implement an algorithm ...** in other Stack Exchange Sites like **CS** or **programmers**?

Comment: @STaefi I agree that this isn't a good question for StackOverflow.  But saying that this is not a Q&A site goes way too far, I think, and could confuse people who do have good questions.

Comment: @ajb: Agree, you are right. Thanks for the hint. ;-)

Comment: My sincerest apology for forgetting to include my code, i have just updated the content.

Comment: @ajb thread updated.

Comment: @STaefi thread updated.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst thread updated.

Comment: Thank you for including the code.  So what's the problem now?  All I can see is a spelling error.

Comment: @ajb thanks for the heads up!! coding over a long span of time can blind me from stupid mistakes likes this sometimes... I kept thinking my algorithm was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the great hints and suggestions, just revised my code and it did the trick!

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    if(array.length == 0 || array.length == 1)
        return true;

    if(start >= end)
        return true;

    if(array[start] != array[end])
        return false;

    return isPalindrome(array, start + 1, end -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- an empty or 1 character string is a palindrome.
- a string is a palindrome if the first and later characters are the same AND ... you figure out the rest.
- a common pattern in recursive algorithms is to use an auxiliary function that does the work.

Answer (score 0):

We have to check till half of the array length and keep comparing the first half to the second.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,0,0,1,0,0,1};
        if(ispalindrome(0,a.length,a))
            System.out.println("Is Palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println("Is not Palindrome");
    }
static boolean ispalindrome(int i, int n, int[] arr) {
        if(i>=n/2)
            return true;
        
        if(arr[i]!=arr[n-i-1])
            return false;
        
        return ispalindrome(i+1,n,arr);
    }
```